# Given a sorted list of integers of length N, determine if an element x is in the list

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search, sortedlist

The problem to solve is:

> Given a sorted list of integers of length N, determine if an element x is in the list without performing any multiplication, division, or bit-shift operations. Do this in O(log N) time.

I have solved this problem using a modified binary search, but I'm not sure if this satisfies the time complexity required. Is there a better solution?

```
def get_mid(start, end):
    mid = start + 1
    sum_ = start + end
    prev = mid
    while mid < end and (mid + mid) != sum_ and (mid + mid + 1) != sum_:
        prev = mid
        mid += mid
    if mid > end:
        return prev
    return mid



def bin_search(arr, x):
    start, end = 0, len(arr) - 1

    while start <= end:
        mid = get_mid(start, end)
        if mid == 1:
            return x in arr[:end]
        if x > arr[mid]:
            start = mid + 1
        elif x < arr[mid]:
            end = mid - 1
        else:
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: Binary search is O(log n), that's precisely the method you should use.

Comment: But I'm not sure how to do binary search without dividing by 2.

Comment: If  you're not sure there's a problem, you likely do not have a Stack Overflow issue ... yet.  Just what part of your implementation do you think is *not* **O(n log n)**, and why?

Comment: @Prune I think it might be the `while` loop in `get_mid()`, which is needed to satisfy the prohibition against division.

Comment: @Prune yup as Barma said.. I also searched for any ideas to do division by 2 without division, and I have found only the subtraction method which takes O(num) and it’s not a good choice for the problem..

Comment: Consider using the python [bisect_left](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html), function instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find the index of `x` if it exists by constructing the index bit-by-bit:

```
def find_idx_sorted(arr, x):
    powers_of_two = [1]
    while powers_of_two[-1] < len(arr):
        powers_of_two.append(powers_of_two[-1] + powers_of_two[-1])

    idx = 0
    for pot in reversed(powers_of_two):
        if idx + pot < len(arr) and x >= arr[idx + pot]:
           idx += pot
    
    return idx
```

Then all we need to do:

```
def contains_sorted(arr, x):
    return arr[find_idx_sorted(arr, x)] == x
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it in O(logN) time, binary search must be used. So, the key point here is to find a way to do division by 2 without multiplication, division, and bit-shift.
Here is a function to do in constant time:

```
int divideTwo(int x) {
    vector<int> bit = {
        0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8,
        0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80,
        0x100, 0x200, 0x400, 0x800,
        0x1000, 0x2000, 0x4000, 0x8000,
        0x10000, 0x20000, 0x40000, 0x80000,
        0x100000, 0x200000, 0x400000, 0x800000,
        0x1000000, 0x2000000, 0x4000000, 0x8000000,
        0x10000000, 0x20000000, 0x40000000, 0
    };

    int v = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < bit.size() - 1 && x > 0; ++i) {
        if ((x & bit[i]) > 0)
        {
            v += bit[i - 1];
            x -= bit[i];
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find with just addition and no loops using log2(N) calls:

```
def find_pos(step, arr, val):
    next = step+step
    if next < len(arr):
       choose = find_pos(next, arr, val)
    else:
       choose = step
    next = choose + step
    if next < len(arr) and arr[next] <= val:
        return next
    if arr[choose] <= val:
        return choose
    return 0

def find_val(arr, val):
    index = find_pos(1, arr, val)
    if arr[index] == val:
        print "found %d at %d" % (val, index)
    else:
        print "%d not found" % (val)
```